# missing required architecture i386 in file. Error

Tags: iphone, graphics, rotation

I am using a code to make 3d Rotation

CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) :

If I remove this line from my project it works perfectly. But if I add it an error comes i.e

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CATransform3DMakeRotation", referenced

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

What Should I do to make it work..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you have to import **QuartzCore** framework (choose your application target and then under "link binary with libraries" add that framework)